# issue with python Idle on fedora

Tags: python, keyboard, fedora, python-idle, x11

When running python idle on my fedora machine, sometimes the keyboard will suddenly frozen and I have to restart idle again.

So I tried "idle -n," and got error messages like the following:

```
"
Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'newsift.py' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 15131 error_code 3 request_code 15 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
[root@poodle tmp]# idle -n

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 122
    set_interactive(1)
RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
"
```

Could anyone tell me what happened? And how shall I fix this? Thank you very much!